# AngularFire2 return only last selected document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to get a simple (in my mind) 2 step query from the firestore using AngularFire2 but I can't seem to understand yet what to do.

```
    getProfile(): Observable<User>{
    return this.afAuth.authState.map(user => {          
      return this.db.doc<User>('user/'+user.uid).valueChanges();
    });
  }
```

I keep getting the following: Type 'Observable>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'User'. Property 'name' is missing in type 'Observable'.

What, pray tell, am I missing here

Comment: did you try with: getProfile(): Observable<any> ?

Comment: I did, but not the solution I am looking for, because then I have to subscribe and subscribe again.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at the [FireBase documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md), my recommendation would be as follows:

```
getProfile(): Observable<User>{
  return this.afAuth.authState.map(user => {          
    return this.db.doc<User>('user/'+user.uid)
                                      .valueChanges()
                                      .map(fUser=>{
                                            // code here to construct user object if needed
                                           return fUser;
                                       });
  });
}
```

**Explanation**

Since FireBase have their variables stored using the following design:

```
user: Observable<any[]>';
constructor( ... ){
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
}
```

You need to extract the individual user object from the Observable returned from valueChanges(), either by means of using the map() function.

I also created a [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nb5t1c?file=app/app.component.ts) to show a proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually got it working with flatMap, had issues with adding the operator previously, that's why i tried working with plain map

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have been correct that the answer is simple:

```
   getProfile$(): Observable<User>{
    return this.afAuth.authState.flatMap(user => {
      return this.db.doc<User>('user/'+user.uid).valueChanges();
    });
  }
```

Not good to try to understand Observables @ midnight